# Spring Flux sends all data only at the end of the connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I want to create SSEEmitter which will send server time every second. I did this using Flux like that:

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/flux", produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
@ResponseBody
fun flux(): Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1L)).map {
        sequence -> ServerSentEvent.builder<String>()
            .id(sequence.toString())
            .event("heartbeat")
            .data("SSE - " + Instant.now().epochSecond.toString())
            .build()
    }
}
```

However, this code sends all ServerSentEvents when the connection becomes closed
[image: Postman]
How to make ServerSentEvents work progressively, so they would work on the method below

```js
const eventSource = new EventSource('/dashboard/updates');
eventSource.onmessage = (msg) => console.log(msg);
```

I also tried making SSEEmitters without Flux like that:

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/updates", produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADS')")
@ResponseBody
fun updates(): SseEmitter {
    val emitter = SseEmitter()
    emitters.add(emitter)
    return emitter
}
```

Using scheduled updates

```kotlin
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
protected fun ping() {
    emitters.forEach { emitter ->
        try {
            emitter.send("Something")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

But it works the same as the flux method before did

Comment: What client do you use to retrieve events ?

Comment: @amanin If I understand you right, I use standart js EventSource, but in debug purposes I used curl and postman

Comment: Your first function `fun flux(): Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>>` should be fine. I"ve copy-paste it into a `@RestController` in a new webflux project (generating with [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io)), and it works fine. Curl receives an event every second. What version of webflux do you use ? Where have you defined the function ?

Comment: Also, as we see in your screenshot, the event contains correct epoch second information (incremented every second). It means that the flux has been correctly triggered upon connection, and that it has fired an event every second. Now, what happened between there (spring controller) and your client, I wonder. Maybe an agressive buffering policy somewhere ? Or a proxy meddling between the spring app and your client ?

Comment: @amanin Thank you very much for your suggestion to check proxy meddling between the spring app and your client! It seems to be an issue with Nginx. Without it everything works fine